# How to create and use a multi-select list in APEX ORACLE?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a table called Employees with Employee_id and Employee_Name columns. Now i want to create a page with Checkbox in-front of every Employee Name, select the ones that are needed, store them into a temporary table and use them for further operations. The problem i am facing is to how to create that multi select list and store the select values in thee table. Is there an Item for multi select? If not, how should i do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's the **Shuttle item**. On the left side, you'd display list of all employees. Item buttons allow you to move all (or only some of them) to the right side of the item. Once you submit the page, list of employee IDs is stored into a table column in a form of colon-separated values, for example

```
6547:8879:5587:9987
```

This is a simple way of doing that. However, once you have to actually *do* something with those values, you have to split them to rows. Not a problem, though. Here's a query:

```
SQL> with emps (shuttle_item) as
  2    (select '6547:8879:5587:9987' from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(shuttle_item, '[^:]+', 1, level) one_item
  4  from emps
  5  connect by level <= regexp_count(shuttle_item, ':') + 1;

ONE_ITEM
---------------------------------------------------------------------
6547
8879
5587
9987

SQL>
```

Or, you could create a tabular form which also displays all employees and has checkboxes at the beginning of every line. You'd then create a process which - in a loop - stores selected values into a *temporary table* you mentioned. For example:

```
-- F01 = row selector. If you check 1st and 3rd row, f01.count = 2 (2 rows checked)
--       f01(1) = 1 (row #1), f01(2) = 3 (row #3)
-- F02 = EMP_ID. f02(1) = EMP_ID that belongs to employee in 1st row, 
--       f02(3) = EMP_ID that belongs to emplyee in 3rd row
declare
  l_id number;
begin
  for j in 1 .. apex_application.g_f01.count
  loop
    l_id := apex_application.g_f02(apex_application.g_f01(j));

    insert into temp_table (emp_id) values (l_id);
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: for the second method, is there an inbuilt feature to create a tabular form (report or grid) to add checkboxes for every row or is that to be done manually?

Comment: Yes; when creating a page, choose "Legacy Page" - you'll see the "Tabular form" in there.

Comment: thanks for your help. It worked. I used a create view statement to make used of those values temporarily. Although creating that view using a dynamic action isn't working. I am able to create it through the SQL Commands tab but not within the application. 
Code is something like :-
    `begin
    execute immediate 'create view as <your query>';
    commit;
    end;`
There might be an issue in passing the item value to the query but i am not sure though. Can you help in this?

Comment: What does it mean, "it isn't working"? Is there any error? If so, which one? Theoretically, that *should* work. However, I wouldn't suggest you to create views (or table or whatever else) *dynamically*. Create a view as you already did - in SQL Workshop. Another question is: do you really need it? Why wouldn't you simply use the above query as an inline view, directly in Apex?

Comment: i am using this because i want to map one customer with a set of employees. Let's say i have 3 customers and 10 team members. e.g. Customer1 -> Employee2, 3, 4 ; Customer2 -> Employee1, 8, 9 and so on. This mapping keeps on changing every month, It's not fixed. And i want to retain this mapping till the end of the month. So i guess i do need it. This is the question i posted which might help you understand the situation better.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50585001/how-to-create-view-using-dynamic-action-in-apex-oracle

Comment: If the list is too big, the browser search field is useful to find the items. Also in the query is recommendable to order the list by the display value (first field in the select)

Answer (score 3):

There is an option for creating multi select list in oracle apex 5.1.

1. Create a pageItem of type: 'select list'.
2. Make the 'Allow multi
   selection' to 'Yes'.
3. Write the SQL query for your select list under
   the 'List of Values' attribute.
4. Then the select list will be
   displayed based on our query.

Query format is:

```
select [displayValue],
       [returnValue]
  from ...
 where ...
 order by ...
```

Now once you select multiple value from select list(using ctrl+click), these are stored as ':' separated values in the select list page item.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a video some times ago that covers your problem. It's a step by step tutorial how to create checkboxes and process them.

Video is available here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-LXRMWQbPk

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If the list is too big, I recommend to use the `Popup LOV` item with the `Multiple Values` switch activated instead the `Select list` or the `Shuttle`, because it has an internal search field for the objects list, doing way easier for the user to find the target values. Also, just as the `Select List` or `Shuttle` item, you can set a `Separator` character for the selected fields.