# How to create view using dynamic action in APEX oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I created a procedure to create a view dynamically using a shuttle item in APEX that returns the colon separated values. Here's the code to create it.

```
create or replace procedure create_temporary_view (input_employees in varchar2) is
begin
execute immediate 'create or replace view temp_batch_id as with emps(shuttle_item) as 
(select '''||input_employees||''' from dual)
select regexp_substr(shuttle_item, ''[^:]+'', 1, level) batch_id from emps connect by level <= regexp_count(shuttle_item, '':'') + 1;';
commit;
end;
```

And inside the Execute PL/SQL code dynamic action i added the code something like

```
begin
create_temporary_view(:P12_EMPLOYEES);
end;
```

where :P12_EMPLOYEES is the shuttle item giving the colon separated values.
Apparently this piece of code works when i do it from the SQL Commands tab in Oracle APEX but the procedure isn't getting called from the EXECUTE PL/SQL code dynamic action. Is there a specific reason for it? If yes, what is it? If not, what could be the possible errors? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why you would need to perform such a task. What is it you're trying to solve?

Comment: I want to map one customer with a set of employees. Let's say i have 3 customers and 10 team members. e.g. Customer1 -> Employee2, 3, 4 ; Customer2 -> Employee1, 8, 9 and so on. This mapping keeps on changing every month, It's not fixed. And i want to retain this mapping till the end of the month. Task related to this view creation will be handled only by one user. Later i intend to pass the customer_id as a parameter so as to create separate view for each customer. So the view name for every customer would be like `temp_batch_id_<customer_id>` .

Comment: It sounds like you should modify your table design to accommodate this sort of information, rather than dynamically moulding your DDL around the problem, eg: cust_emp_link table containing cust_id, emp_id, month

Comment: Then i will just take another table to store that information and delete the data at the end of month. Although i still would like to know as to why it doesn't work. Thanks @Scott

Comment: Try remove the final semi-colon within the string. And you should see these errors somewhere.

Comment: I already did that @Scott. It just passes without doing anything. No errors..nothing..

Comment: I saw them as I ran your code in SQL Developer. You would probably see them in APEX's debug log.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's your final goal, but I wouldn't create any table or view from APEX like that.

I think you actually want to populate a collection.

Have a look at how to create/populate collection in APEX and I think you'll find whatever you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to tokenize your `P12_EMPLOYEES` variable. This is not the right way to do this. Apex has a built-in PL/SQL function for doing this:

```
apex_string.split( :P12_EMPLOYEES, ':' )
```

this will give you a `apex_t_varchar2` collection, split by colons.

Why your approach is a bad idea, consider what happens if two users are using your application at the same time. You'll create a view visible to both users with data from only one.

Comment: I want to map one customer with a set of employees. Let's say i have 3 customers and 10 team members. e.g. Customer1 -> Employee2, 3, 4 ; Customer2 -> Employee1, 8, 9 and so on. This mapping keeps on changing every month, It's not fixed. And i want to retain this mapping till the end of the month. Task related to this view creation will be handled only by one user. Later i intend to pass the customer_id as a parameter so as to create separate view for each customer. So the view name for every customer would be like `temp_batch_id_<customer_id>`

Comment: All that data belongs in a table. Storing data and relationships is what tables are *for*. It sounds like you want one with two columns customer_id and employee_id.