# Oracle Apex LOV return mutiple value just like forms 6i lov

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Oracle Apex LOV return mutiple value just like forms 6i lov

in interactive grid layout how to return mutiple value if user select from list 
 PLEASE SEE PICTURE

[LOV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UCdX.png)

[Region detail interactive grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znvGo.png)

[ig PAGE ITEM TO ig COLUMN VALUE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cg6IK.png)

[Dyanmic action on ig column and set value from page item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgEl1.png)

Comment: Does [this answer help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50560072/146325)?

Comment: APC linked a good answer, but if that doesent work for you you could also do Parent LOVs, so when you select one field it restricts what can be selected in others. Or have the first column be all the relevant values concacted and when its changed use that value with a DA to fill the other columns.

Comment: Kindly see picture upload

Answer (score 0):

I just created an Interactive Grid and set one of the columns to be a Popup LOV. In the settings for that column, I saw this:

[image]

Once I enabled Multiple Values, I was able to select multiple values:

[image]

If that doesn't answer your question, please update your question with more detail as to what you're trying to do. The pictures you provide are not enough to understand.